# Concatenate by mirroring same valuecolumns of different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, mirroring

I just want to make one dataframe (df3) with concatenate and by mirroring same columns values of two different dataframes (df1 and df2). Its just an example my datasets are way bigger.

```
> df1
  id_synthese1 format_1 ville
0             .dat       tours                      
1             .map       bordeaux
2             .sig       marseille                       

> df2
  id_synthese2 format_2  etude
0             .map       environnement                      
1             .sig       geotec
2             .dat       sismique
```

I would like an output like

```
> df3
  id_synthese1 format_1 ville       id_synthese2      format_2     etude    
0             .dat       tours                  2     .dat         sismique
1             .map       bordeaux               0     .map         environnement
2             .sig       marseille              1     .sig         geotec
```

The "mirroring" is between the columns: format_1 and format_2

I have tried

```
df3= pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['format_1','format_2'], how='outer')
```

and

```
df3= df1.join(
    df2.set_index(['format_1','format_2']),
    lsuffix="_x",
    rsuffix="_y",
    on=['format_1','format_2'])
```

and

```
df3= pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Thank you (i know that's an easy one... I am a beginner)

Comment: where does `format_brute1` and `format_brute2` come into this?  I can't see them in your dataframes

Comment: My bad i have changed the names. I tried with the right dataframes names format_1 and format_2. I have made the modification thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass `left_on = "format_1"` and `right_on = "format_2"` instead of `on` parameter in your `pd.merge` call

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Thank you very much ! I found out that one of my datasets was not the good one also. Now it's working perfectly thanks to you